# Shiny Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, json, r, shiny

I have a shiny app which works locally. However when I upload the app and database to my server, I get the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

I went into the console, and saw it was on a JSON.Parse(msg) line.  I got the 'msg' value, and put it into [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/).  The 'msg' code looks like this:

```
"{"errors": { }, "values":   ... etc ...
```

The jsonlint debugger said the following:

```
Parse error on line 1:
"{    "errors": { 
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

As far as I'm aware I don't have much or any control over JSON.parse calls in a shiny app.  Also, it does not look like an issue with my data.  Any ideas on how I can get around this?

**EDIT**

There was a weird data issue in the msg which I have now resolved.

After investigating further I found that **any JSON.parse() msg which works or doesn't, copied into jsonlint.com, gives the above error.**

Is this something to do with shiny's or bootstrap's code conversion?

Hopefully this will help other shinyapp developers - the above error may not exist, or be the one causing the app to break.

Comment: you don't start a json string with a double quote, is what the lint is complaining about

Comment: Thanks.  However since I'm not creating the JSON 'msg' myself, I guess my question is how can I get around this within my R code?  It works locally (Windows), but not on the server (Linux).  Is it possible shiny concatenates the 'msg' for JSON.parse differently?